# Pyscipopt does not handle 1/variable and variable^(negative number) in the objective function

Tags: python-3.x, scip

I am trying to solve a large-scale nonlinear problem. Below is the objective function coded for pyscipopt. I have some loops over a list of tuples (r,p,s) in the list RouteTimeStop, and the only variable is headway[pat]. When I looped over RouteTimeStop, the solver stuck at the objective function creation and did not produce any progress for quite a long time. Then, I tried to see what is going on and considered first 200 tuples of the list.

```
### BEGIN DECLARING THE MODEL ###
m = Model('CTA')
### END DECLARING THE MODEL ###

### BEGIN ADDING VARIABLES INTO THE MODEL m ###
headway = {}
for pat in Pattern:
    headway[pat] = m.addVar(vtype = "C", lb = 1, ub = 30, name = "headway (%s)"%(pat))
print("Added the variables.")
### END ADDING VARIABLES INTO THE MODEL m ###

### BEGIN INTRODUCING THE OBJECTIVE FUNCTION INTO m ###
m.setObjective(quicksum(b/2/(1-el[r,p,s])*con2[r,p,s]*(30**(1-el[r,p,s])
             -(quicksum(pattern_ratio[r,p,s,pat]*30*headway[pat] for pat in RTSPdict[r,p,s])/30)
             **(el[r,p,s]-1)) for (r,p,s) in RouteTimeStop[:200])
             + quicksum(con[r,p,s]*quicksum(pattern_ratio[r,p,s,pat]*30*headway[pat]
             for pat in RTSPdict[r,p,s])**el[r,p,s] for (r,p,s) in RouteTimeStop[:200]),
             'maximize')
print("Added the objective function.")
### END INTRODUCING THE OBJECTIVE FUNCTION ###
```

The solver produced the following error.

```
Added the variables.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-164bed181b42> in <module>
     11 
     12 ### BEGIN INTRODUCING THE OBJECTIVE FUNCTION INTO m ###
---> 13 m.setObjective(quicksum(b/2/(1-el[r,p,s])*con2[r,p,s]*(30**(1-el[r,p,s])
     14        -(quicksum(pattern_ratio[r,p,s,pat]*30*headway[pat] for pat in RTSPdict[r,p,s])/30)
     15                 **(el[r,p,s]-1)) for (r,p,s) in RouteTimeStop[:200])

src/pyscipopt/scip.pyx in pyscipopt.scip.Model.setObjective()

AssertionError: given coefficients are neither Expr or number but SumExpr
```

After playing a bit with the objective function, I realized number **/** variable and variable **^** number are not accepted in the objective function. How can I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

SCIP does not support nonlinear objective functions. You can reformulate the problem by introducing another variable and moving the objective into a constraint:

```
max objvar subject to:
    objvar <= f
```

where `f` is the actual nonlinear objective.

Comment: I tried this, and got to m.optimize() without an error. However, I couldn't get any prints for a day. Ipopt was able to start reporting iteration info after around 20 minutes.

Comment: Can you please share a reproducible example?